# What is the best approach to deal with batches within a Lambda layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I created a neural network with Keras, and added a Lambda layer to perform some calculations, but it is showing a poor performance on inferences.

I was able to make the inferences successfully using a batch of one input and added one more loop to handle multiple inputs. Everything works fine, but the performance is somewhat poor. I figured using a larger batch would make things a lot faster. My question is whether I am handling batches correctly (is it really necessary to use another loop?) as I have not found any keras or tensorflow documentation dealing with this topic in more depth.
Below is a code with a structure similar to the one I'm using in the Lambda layer.

```py
def GenericFunc(x, batch=10, channels=64):
    y, group = [], []
    for i in range(batch):
        for j in range(channels):
            y.append(backend.sum(x[0, :, :, j]))
        group.append(tf.convert_to_tensor(y, dtype=np.float32))
        y = []
    yy = backend.stack(group, axis=0)
    tensor_stack = backend.reshape(yy, [batch,channels])
    return tensor_stack
```

Any suggestions will be welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never use loops. Tensors are made for tensor operations.

```
def GenericFunc(x):
    y = backend.sum(x, axis=1)
    y = backend.sum(y, axis=1)
    return y
```

Probably also works with

```
def GenericFunc(x):
    return backend.sum(x, axis=[1,2])
```